# IE iframe download causing security warning

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, iframe

My application takes AJAX requests and responds with a URL to a download location on my website for the file they're requesting. Then the Javascript AJAX method for success of the response, dynamically creates an iframe on the page with the src set to the download location, to allow the file dialog to display so the user can download the file. The problem is IE displays the following security warning:

http://avnhelp.com/default_files/image004.jpg

The main reason this is a problem is because, when they click accept, it refreshes the page and the file download is lost (I'm assuming this is because it's in an iframe created dynamically).

I need a way to either:

- disable this security dialog prompt
- prompt the user when they visit the
  site to accept any future file
  downloads.
- fix the fact that upon refresh (from 
  accepting) the file download is lost.

Here is my iframe code:

```
function create_iframe(url) {
    frame = document.createElement('IFRAME');
    frame.setAttribute('src', url);
    frame.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
}
```

If someone could help me with this, that'd be great! Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `iframe` for file download. If you need to download from external website build server side proxy that will use some kind of `HttpRequest` then use jQuery AJAX to access the local proxy.

Comment: What is your server side language? PHP, ASP.NET or something else?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: HttpRequest to trigger a file download? You have clearly misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Sean I thought he was trying to download file from external website.

Comment: just as a side note, i dont think the jquery tag applies to this question ... no big deal, just wanted to point it out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't disable the security warning. The browser will act like that whenever a file attachment shows up in an HTTP response that's not related to an HTTP request made from a user-initiated event ("click" or form submit). You're getting the warning because you're making the HTTP request from the ajax response event handler, and the browser simply does not like that.

The only way to make the setup work is to make sure that you start the HTTP request from a "click" handler, or the "submit" handler for a form (or by having the actual form submit result in the file response).

Comment: Hi Pointy, thanks for your response. So basically there's not really any way to do what I'm after without an extra click involved? That was really my main goal here, to eliminate having to click a link or a button or a form or something, to make it as 'less interaction' as possible.

Comment: Yes, it is a pain, but the browser does that to prevent nasty bad websites from sending malicious downloads to people.